# How to escape "\"String\"" in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am making a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request, and the POST request returns the string in this format:

```
"\"1231231231323213\""
```

I need to use this string to make another call.

When I do

```
var NewLocationId = response.Content;
Logger.LogInfo($"LocationID : {NewLocationId}");
```

I get

> LocationID : "1231231231323213"

But when I debug it, the value of `NewLocationId` is `"\"1231231231323213\""`.

When I use the value of NewLocationId in my request call the JSON content looks like this:

```
{"locationId":"\"1231231231323213\""}
```

How can I escape `"\"1231231231323213\""` to `"1231231231323213"`?

#### The next version

```
var response = Call.PostNewLocation(SomeValue123, SomeValue1234, null, SomeValue);
var NewLocationId = response.Content;
Logger.LogInfo($"LocationID : {NewLocationId}");
var responseDevice = Call.PostNewDevice(SomeValue, SomeValue22, SomeValue3, SomeValue1, NewLocationId);
```

When I try to use the response content from the above call I am getting back this string `"1231231231323213"` the debugger shows `"\"1231231231323213\""`

And then when I use `NewLocationId` in my next call the JSON content looks like this:

```
{...,"locationId":"\"1231231231323213\"",...}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, what you are seeing is a string that looks like: `"1231231231323213"`, including the leading and trailing double-quote.  The debugger represents a double-quote in a string in C# fashion as `\"`.  If you don't want the quotes, strip them off

Comment: The debugger is showing you the quotes as `\"`, but that notation is simply a representation of `"`

Comment: But, do you really want the quotes?  If you use your string without the quotes, then your JSON will look like `{"locationId":"1231231231323213"}`, which is what I think you want

Comment: @Flydog57 I have edited my question hope it makes it more clear, My Desired Output is `"1231231231323213"`

Comment: To repeat, one more time.  Your string doesn't contain any backslashes.  If you were to look at it as a UTF-8 byte array (in hex), you'd see `22-31-32-33-...-32-31-33-22`, where the 3x numbers are the digits and the 22s are the double quotes.  The debugger represents the double-quotes as `\"`.  But, if you want to have `{"locationId":"1231231231323213"}`, you need to strip the double-quotes from your string

Comment: Use the Text Visualizer in the debugger to see the undecorated string.  Click on the spyglass icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Trim()` to remove the additional quotes around your string. Note, that this will only work for quotes on the very beginning or end of the string.

```
NewLocationId = NewLocationId.Trim('\"');
```

If you need the to also remove quotes inbetween the rest of the string, use `String.Replace("\"", "")`:

Alternatively, if it is always the same "structure" always strip first and last character, this might execute faster:

```
NewLocationId = NewLocationId.Substring(1, NewLocationId.Length - 2);
```

Comment: Its always the same structure, That helped me thank :)

Answer (score 2):

The debugger is just showing you that the actual string value contains quotation marks. If you don't *want* the value to contain quotes, you can use `String.Replace` to remove them. If you *do* want them, there's nothing for you to do.